# Mathematica calculates the parameter value when the first derivative is 0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to get the value of the corresponding parameter *t* when *dil=0* or *dvc=0*. What method can I use?

```
sol1 = DSolve[{l il'[t] == vl[t], c vc'[t] == ic[t], 
    ir[t] == -ic[t] + il[t], vl[t] == 24 - vc[t], vr[t] == vc[t], 
    vr[t] == r ir[t], il[0] == 0, vc[0] == 0}, {ir[t], il[t], ic[t], 
    vr[t], vl[t], vc[t]}, t];
{il[t_], vc[t_]} = {il[t], vc[t]} /. sol1[[1]];
pars1 = {r -> 22, l -> 2 10^-1, c -> 1 10^-4};
a = Evaluate[il[t] /. pars1] // Simplify;
b = Evaluate[vc[t] /. pars1] // Simplify;
dil = D[a, t] // Simplify
dvc = D[b, t] // Simplify
```

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2843364).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get the value of the corresponding parameter t when dil=0 or
> dvc=0.

One way is to use the `Solve` command

```
dil = D[a, t] // Simplify
Solve[dil == 0, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dvc = D[b, t] // Simplify
Solve[dvc == 0, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice it also says

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some
> solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution
> information.

---

Using `Reduce` gives

```
Reduce[dil == 0, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Reduce[dvc == 0, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Reduce` also has option `Reals` which you might want to consider using.

Comment: Why does this happen? If Reduce is used, it is not an accurate solution......

Comment: @chenchen You could try and use the option `Reals` with Reduce to see if it now gives the solution you think should be the correct one.